# C++ Elegant Array Slicing

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, initializer-list

I would like to pass multiple, non-contiguous values from an array to a method.  This is currently working:

```
double constexpr args[]{ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 };
void example(std::initializer_list<double>);
example({ args[1], args[3], args[4] });
```

In order to simplify the call, I would instead prefer to provide the arguments without the need to repeat the `args` variable along with each index.  The following is what I attempted (I know all the indexes at compile-time):

```
template<size_t... I, typename T, size_t S>
std::initializer_list<T> get(T const (&array)[S]) {
    return { array[I]... };
}

example(get<1, 3, 4>(args));
```

However, the above call to the example method is passing what appears to be uninitialized memory (I am populating a vector from the initializer_list, and it ends up containing junk values like 6.95278e-310).  Can anyone see what is wrong with my implementation of the `get` method?

Comment: To fix this just return a `std::array<T, sizeof...(I)>` instead.

Comment: That solution works in my case, since the items I am trying to pass are light.  However, in the general case, it may be preferable to return an `std::array<T const *, sizeof...(I)>` and change the result to return `&array[I]...` to prevent copying each item.